# Accessing Protected Functions from Another Class - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, inheritance, protected

I have two files, `Main.as`, and `Book.as`.

**Book.as** is as follows:

```
public class Book extends sprite
{
  protected function addPage():void
  {
    var title:Sprite = new Sprite();
    addChild(title);
  }
}
```

I am trying to create an instance of Book, and eventually add it to the stage. How do I access this protected function? (I cannot change `Book.as`, as it is part of a project).

I am doing the following in **Main.as**:

```
var newBook:Book = new Book();
newBook.addPage();
```

Basically, how do I access `addPage`? I am using `extends Sprite` for my Main class.

Comment: The simplest way is extending the Book class (as noted by LDMS), but you can try the Reflection API...

Comment: AS3 is too strict with private and protected methods, there's no ways to get access to them even with a reflection API.

Comment: Is this the entire `Book` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected functions can only be called from that class, or a class that extends it

Looking at that class though, it's quite useless being a protected function. Either get who ever you need to make it public, or to create some other function that calls it (like in the constructor for instance).

If this is something you need to absolutely do without changing `Book.as`, then this is your only option as I see it:

Create a subclass of `Book`.  eg:

```
public class MyBook extends Book {
    public function addMe():void {
        addPage();
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var newBook:MyBook = new MyBook();
newBook.addMe();
```

Comment: The simplest one, but, there is a big problem with this approach, though... If the Book class cannot be changed (it part of a lib), most likely that this class is used elsewhere and the instances are handed over to the user... If this is the case, extending is not possible.

Comment: @NemoStein - True,  but in the question the only example of this class is instantiated by them.  Besides, the only purpose of a class like that, is to be extended. This smells like homework.

Comment: @NemoStein has a good point but LDMS provides the absolute only way to access that protected function. As mentioned this solution might end up generating its own share of problems if part of a swc.